# Skeleton of a continuous Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains

I have a continuous Markov Chain with  transition matrix $\Bbb P$ and with initial state $X_0=1$ and state space $I=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$
$$\Bbb P= \begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & -3 & 1 \\
0 & 1  & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I have to find the discrete skeleton of matrix P,that in my exercise results:$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \frac13 & 0 & \frac13 & \frac13\\
\frac13 & 0 & \frac13 & 0 & \frac13 \\
0 & \frac12 & 0 & 0 & \frac12 \\
\frac12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac12 \\
\frac14 & \frac14  & \frac14 & \frac14 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

I searched a lot on internet a good definition and a way to compute the matrix ,but i find nothing.

Comment: @JimmyR. No,i find it on an exercise gives us in a lesson,but i searched on internet a definition but i find nothing :(

Comment: Now the second matrix is a transition matrix... which corresponds to neither of the two discretizatons of the process whose generator is the first matrix that one could think about.

Comment: I'm sorry if i am confused ,but this topic is fairly new to me , i just copied down the solutions that my TA gave in class,i don't know  how to solve it and i would appreciate some hints on how to proceed.I didn't understand completely your last comment

Comment: The obvious move is to go back to your TA and ask them for the definition of *skeleton* in this context (that is, if said definition was not already given to you, which somehow I doubt).

Comment: @Did Thank you.I would have done it , if the TA was avaible ,which is not.Could you provide some links where they explain this concept because i can't find it anywhere online.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain#Embedded_Markov_chain . What you have looks  odd.

Comment: As I said, there are two possible discretizations of a continuous Markov process $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb R_+}$ that can be called its skeleton. Either one fixes a times step $\delta$ and one defines $(\xi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ by $\xi_n=X_{n\delta}$. Or one considers the sequence $(\eta_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of different states occupied by $(X_t)$, that is, one defines recursively $\tau_0=0$ and $\tau_{n+1}=\inf\{t>\tau_n\mid X_t\ne X_{\tau_n}\}$, and one sets $\eta_n=X_{\tau_n}$. Your second matrix works neither for $(\xi_n)$ nor for $(\eta_n)$.